# Horizontal longtable is not splitting over multiple pages

Tags: tables, longtable, landscape

I am trying to create a long, horizontal table in LaTeX spanning multiple pages. The table was originally created in word format and it would be too time-consuming to code the table from scratch (I have to repeat the process with other similarly sized tables), so I have been using the website [Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/#) to help with the conversion process. In the options, I checked the following options to be ON:

- Escape special TeX symbols
- Compress whitespace
- Smart output formatting
- Caption above
- Center table horizontally
- Scale table to text width
- Rotate table (landscape model)
- Split table in multiple pages
- Add table continuation header

I have created a fully compilable version of the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{lscape}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
% \usepackage{lscape}
% \usepackage{longtable}
% Note: It may be necessary to compile the document several times to get a multi-page table to line up properly
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[c]{llllllllllll}
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
{\color[HTML]{000000} Loren Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Loren Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Loren Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Loren Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Loren Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Loren Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Loren Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Loren Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Loren Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Loren Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Loren Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Loren Ipsum Dotem} \\
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{12}{c}%
{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
\endhead
%
\rowcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem} &
  {\color[HTML]{000000} Lorem Ipsum Dotem}
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

The packages were implemented into the preamble file as dictated by the output code. The code compiles with no error. However, the table does not split over multiple pages.

[image]

The table cuts abruptly and only uses 1 page, even when the 'longtable' package is used. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, I don't have a lot of experience programming in LaTeX so I wouldn't be surprised if its an easy fix I've overlooked.

Comment: The table is too wide and not long enough.  You need to reverse the columns and rows (transpose) for longtable to help.

Comment: I transposed the table but it still cuts out after 1 page.

Comment: There is only room for 5 columns of this width, and this MWE has 13.  longtable doesn't do anything for excess columns, only rows.

Comment: The table is 12x18 so no matter what I'm going to end up with too large a table for longtable. Do you have any suggestions what I could do to implement the table?

Comment: You could make the columns narrower by allowing linebreaks inside of the cells to save some horizontal space. You can also slightly decrease the font size and the value of `\tabcolsep`. If this still does not work, you might have to split the table into two or more parts. For a more specific advice, please add more information on the nature of teh column contents. Are they numbers, single words, longer text, something else...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

- Use of table generator (always) result in code with lot of clutter, I strongly encourage you to write your tables directly in LaTeX editor. It is not so difficult.
- Your table is much wider than `\textheight`. Consequently it spill out of page.
- This problem can be solved by writing cells content in more lines, i.e. use a table environment, which enable automatic split cells contets into more lines. For example, `xltabular`, which is combination od `longtable` and `tabularx` offer such facility with`X` column type
- With use od many `X` columns in table is sensible use smaller fonts that content in cells can better fill cells

An example of your table after cleaning all clutter caused by used table generator and use of `xltabular` instead of `longtable` is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs, xltabular}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\footnotesize
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} *{12}{X} @{}}
    \caption{On the first page}
\label{tab:my-table}    \\
Loren Ipsum Dotem  &
Loren Ipsum Dotem  &
Loren Ipsum Dotem  &
Loren Ipsum Dotem  &
Loren Ipsum Dotem  &
Loren Ipsum Dotem  &
Loren Ipsum Dotem  &
Loren Ipsum Dotem  &
Loren Ipsum Dotem  &
Loren Ipsum Dotem  &
Loren Ipsum Dotem  &
Loren Ipsum Dotem   \\    
\endfirsthead
%
\caption[]{continued from previous page}    \\
\endhead
% table body
\rowcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem   \\

\rowcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem   \\

\rowcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem   \\

\rowcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem   \\

\rowcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem   \\

Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem   \\

Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem   \\

Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem   \\

Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem   \\

Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem   \\

Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dote    \\

Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem   \\

Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem   \\

Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem   \\

Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  \\

Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  \\

Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem  &
Lorem Ipsum Dotem   \\
\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

*Note*: your table not use any rules. This is quite unusual. People usully add some horizontal lines, for example rules from `booktabs` package, by which they delimit table from surrounding text and column headers from table body.

[image]

(only part of the first part of the table is shown)

Comment: That's helped a lot, thank you!

Comment: @estranged_nunchuck, you are welcome!